# Auto mount network share

Tags: ubuntu, mount, network-share, fstab

Hello i am trying to get my slave media center to mount a network drive at startup automatic.
I have written this to my /etc/fstab/

```
\\192.168.1.2\root /media/data cifs username=doomstone,password=XXXX,auto,user 0 0
\\192.168.1.2\xbmc /media/xbmc cifs username=doomstone,password=XXXX,auto,user 0 0
```

Now when i do a "mount /media/data" it all works just fine, but it dose not mount it on statup. witch is a pain as the computer dose not have a keyboard, only a remote. So i need to ssh the computer and mount the drives each time i boot.
As far as i can figure is that the computer dose not have a network connection at the mount time, and thus fails the mount of the network drives.

How can i do this so it can be mounted at startup?

Comment: I'm brining the problem up again as it did not work, it only worked for 2-3 reboots and then it manuel mount for me again!

Answer (score 12):

Try replacing `auto` with `_netdev` in the options in `/etc/fstab` - this should make the mount wait until the network is up.

Comment: The most underrated fstab option. There are not enough people who know about this, even though it is unspeakably useful. +1

Comment: Cool i will try it when i get home from work

Comment: Thank you.  This is the only place on the internet documenting **_netdev**. :P

Comment: This does NOT work with Samba/CIFS filesystems as noted here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options

Answer (score 0):

Either write `mount /media/{data,xbmc}` to /etc/rc.local (hope it's called so in Ubuntu) or take a look at [autofs](http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs).

Edit: didn't see this, you have to replace your backslashes with "/" in /etc/fstab.

Comment: I have tryed that, it diden't work

Comment: Would have voted you up if you had refrained from mentioning putting stuff into /etc/rc.local. Don't do that, unless there is no other straight-forward way to do something. In this case, there is with either autofs or - and I would prefer this - using _netdev.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent way too much time myself to get this sorted so I'm posting what worked for me, to have Samba 4.9.5 shares automount on boot with Debian Buster 10.5. The /etc/fstab line I initially had was something like:

```
//server/music /mnt/music cifs ro,vers=3.0,guest,_netdev 0 0
```

With the line above (using `_netdev`) my `/var/log/syslog` reported failures in name resolution, so I tried to amend the configuration using the server's IP address. This did not work either, with the errors logged being rather useless:

```
Sep 14 18:52:05 hostname systemd[1]: mnt-music.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 14 18:52:05 hostname systemd[1]: mnt-music.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

At this point it's important to note, more so because this is the most relevant search result and it's straight up false and misleading, that the `_netdev` option is **useless** with Samba/CIFS mounts, *it only works with NFS* [as specified at point 12 here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options).

What finally did it was replacing `_netdev` with `comment=systemd.automount`, [as suggested by another user here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99014/44724) with the difference that I completely omitted `_netdev`, for a final result like:

```
//server/music /mnt/music cifs ro,vers=3.0,guest,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

This works like a charm, and in my specific scenario mounts 6 different file systems without a problem, making them available right at boot.