# Mount /etc/fstab at startup

Tags: mount, fstab

I already added the remote directories I want mounted at startup in `/etc/fstab`, but when I reboot, they don't get mounted.

If I run `mount -a` it all works, but it appears that `mount -a` doesn't get executed at boot. Is there something I need to enable in order to have them mounted by default?

My fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext3 defaults 1 1
none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
none /proc proc defaults 0 0
none /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/images /var/www/html/images nfs rw 0 0
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/files /var/www/html/sites/default/files nfs rw 0 0
10.190.53.183:/var/www/thumbnails/uploads /var/www/html/uploads nfs rw 0 0
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/vizbox /var/www/html/vizbox nfs rw 0 0
```

and I am running CentOS 5.8

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Comment: Please post your fstab entry

Comment: If your network is not yet up at the time that you try to mounts remote directories (NFS?) then that will fail. This would explain why it works at a later time.

Comment: Updated my question with both info.

Comment: Hmmm: is http://serverfault.com/questions/166224/auto-mount-network-share?rq=1 relavant? I think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that the `netfs` service is enabled. Use either `ntsysv` or `chkconfig` to enable it.

Comment: Will definitely try that.

Comment: Did `netfs` work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Your network's not up at the time of running fstab, just add a 'mount -a' at the end of your rc.local.

Answer (score 2):

I always go on about it but is there a reason you're not/can't use autofs? That way it would mount the NFS shares on demand, not just during startup.

To keep it simple you do do something like

/etc/auto.master

```
/net auto.net
```

/etc/auto.net

```
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/images images 
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/files files 
10.190.53.183:/var/www/thumbnails/uploads uploads 
10.46.7.232:/var/www/html/vizbox vizbox
```

And then set up a load of symlinks

```
ln -s /var/www/html/images /net/images
ln -s /var/www/html/sites/default/files /net/files
ln -s /var/www/html/uploads /net/uploads
ln -s /var/www/html/vizbox /net/vizbox
```

And finally

```
service autofs restart
```

You'll get all kinds of good things like automatically recovering when the NFS server goes down, insulation from errors when the NFS server is not in use.

Comment: it's a more complex setup. I think netfs works well, but autofs is a good long-term move.

Comment: It's funny how perspectives differ, I only use autofs now. I reckon it's nearly as easy to set up as fstab entries and it gets rid of so many other issues. The messing around with symlinks isn't ideal I guess...